# Redux state being overwrite after changing another state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a problem with Redux, when I change view and I make an API call to retrieve data, and I go back to my other view, the data is overwritten by "undefined", yet the two states have no incidence between them.

I have my actions and my reducers separated in two different files and they are well declared in my store which is coupled with redux-persist.

**/screens/delivererNews.js**

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect } from 'react'
import { View, Text, FlatList, StyleSheet, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { getNews } from '../../redux/action/deliverer/news'

const DeliverNews = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const getDeliverNews = useCallback((payload) => dispatch(getNews(payload)), [dispatch])

    const token = useSelector(state => state.login.token)
    const news = useSelector(state => state.news.list)
    const pull_loading = useSelector(state => state.news.pull_loading)
    const loading = useSelector(state => state.news.loading)

    const onRefresh = () => {
        getDeliverNews({ token, pull: true })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getDeliverNews({ token, pull: false })
    }, [])

    return (
        loading ? <ActivityIndicator style={{ flex: 1 }} size="small" color="#E95344" /> :

            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <FlatList
                    data={news}
                    onRefresh={onRefresh}
                    refreshing={pull_loading}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
                        <View style={local.container}>
                            <Text style={local.title}>{item.title}</Text>
                            <Text style={local.content}>{item.content}</Text>
                        </View>
                    )}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                />
            </View>
    )
}

const local = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        margin: 20,
        shadowColor: 'grey',
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 0 },
        shadowOpacity: 0.50,
        shadowRadius: 11,
        borderRadius: 10,
    },
    title: {
        fontFamily: 'Fredoka One',
        fontSize: 20,
        color: '#424242',
        marginHorizontal: 20,
        marginVertical: 10,
    },
    content: {
        fontFamily: 'Fredoka One',
        fontSize: 17,
        color: '#424242',
        marginHorizontal: 20,
        marginBottom: 20,
    },
})

export default DeliverNews
```

**/screens/delivererProfil.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useCallback } from 'react'
import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import CustomButton from '../../components/CustomButton';
import { reset } from '../../redux/action/deliverer/login';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { getProfil } from '../../redux/action/deliverer/profil';

const DeliverProfil = ({ navigation }) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const getDeliverProfil = useCallback((payload) => dispatch(getProfil(payload)), [dispatch])
    const token = useSelector(state => state.login.token)
    const user = useSelector(state => state.login.user)
    const profil = useSelector(state => state.profil.infos)

    useEffect(() => {
        getDeliverProfil({ token: token, id: user.id })
    }, [])

    const telFormat = tel => {
        if (!tel)
            return null
        var parse = tel.match(/.{1,2}/g);
        var telFormatted = parse.join(" ");
        return telFormatted
    }


    return (
        <View style={local.container}>
            <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <Image style={{ width: 90, height: 90, margin: 50 }} source={require('../../assets/img/da_logo.png')} />
            </View>
            <View style={local.fieldContainer}>
                <Image style={{ width: 22, height: 22 }} source={require('../../assets/img/person_red_icon.png')} />
                <Text style={local.textInfos}>{profil?.firstName + ' ' + profil?.lastName}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={local.fieldContainer}>
                <Image style={{ width: 22, height: 24 }} source={require('../../assets/img/red_phone_icon.png')} />
                <Text style={local.textInfos}>{telFormat(profil?.tel)}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={local.fieldContainer}>
                <Image style={{ width: 25, height: 25 }} source={require('../../assets/img/at_icon.png')} />
                <Text style={local.textInfos}>{profil?.email}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={local.fieldContainer}>
                <Image style={{ width: 22, height: 30 }} source={require('../../assets/img/red_map_pin.png')} />
                <Text style={local.textInfos}>{profil?.city}</Text>
            </View>
            <CustomButton
                style={{ marginVertical: 30, marginHorizontal: 20 }}
                label="Déconnexion"
                backgroundColor={'#CD6561'}
                textColor={'white'}
                onPress={() => dispatch(reset())}
            />

        </View>
    )
}

const local = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        margin: 20,
        shadowColor: 'grey',
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 0 },
        shadowOpacity: 0.50,
        shadowRadius: 11,
        borderRadius: 10,
    },
    textInfos: {
        fontFamily: 'Fredoka One',
        fontSize: 17,
        color: '#5A5A5A',
        marginLeft: 15,
    },
    fieldContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginBottom: 15,
        marginHorizontal: 20,
    }

})


export default DeliverProfil
```

**/actions/profil.js**

```
import Request from '../../../axiosConfig';

export const GET_PROFIL_SUCCESS = 'GET_NEWS_SUCCESS'
export const GET_PROFIL_FAILURE = 'GET_NEWS_FAILURE'
export const LOADING = 'LOADING'
export const RESET_LOADING = 'RESET_LOADING'

function loading() {
    return {
        type: LOADING,
    }
}

function resetLoading() {
    return {
        type: RESET_LOADING,
    }
}

function getProfilSuccess(profil) {
    return {
        type: GET_PROFIL_SUCCESS,
        profil: profil,
    }
}

function getProfilFailure(error) {
    return {
        type: GET_PROFIL_FAILURE,
        error,
    }
}

export function getProfil(payload) {
    return async dispatch => {
        dispatch(loading())
        await Request("/deliverer/" + payload.id, "get", null, payload.token)
            .then(function (response) {
                dispatch(resetLoading())
                dispatch(getProfilSuccess(response.data))
                console.log("SUCCESS")
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                    dispatch(resetLoading())
                    dispatch(getProfilFailure(error))
            });
    }
}
```

**/reducers/profil.js**

```
import { GET_PROFIL_SUCCESS, GET_PROFIL_FAILURE, LOADING, RESET_LOADING } from '../../action/deliverer/profil'

export const _INITIAL_STATE_ = {
    loading: false,
}

export default function (state = _INITIAL_STATE_, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case RESET_LOADING: {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
            }
        }
        case LOADING:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true,
                error: null
            }
        case GET_PROFIL_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                profil: action.profil
            }
        case GET_PROFIL_FAILURE:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                error: action.error,
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

**/actions/news.js**

```
import Request from '../../../axiosConfig';

export const GET_NEWS_SUCCESS = 'GET_NEWS_SUCCESS'
export const GET_NEWS_FAILURE = 'GET_NEWS_FAILURE'
export const LOADING = 'LOADING'
export const PULL_LOADING = 'PULL_LOADING'
export const RESET_LOADING = 'RESET_LOADING'
export const RESET_PULL_LOADING = 'RESET_PULL_LOADING'

function loading() {
    return {
        type: LOADING,
    }
}

function pullLoading() {
    return {
        type: PULL_LOADING,
    }
}

function resetLoading() {
    return {
        type: RESET_LOADING,
    }
}

function pullResetLoading() {
    return {
        type: RESET_PULL_LOADING,
    }
}

function getNewsSuccess(news) {
    return {
        type: GET_NEWS_SUCCESS,
        news: news,
    }
}

function getNewsFailure(error) {
    return {
        type: GET_NEWS_FAILURE,
        error,
    }
}

export function getNews(payload) {
    return async dispatch => {
        payload.pull ? dispatch(pullLoading()) : dispatch(loading())
        await Request("/deliverer/news", "get", null, payload.token)
            .then(function (response) {
                payload.pull ? dispatch(pullResetLoading()) : dispatch(resetLoading())
                dispatch(getNewsSuccess(response.data))
                console.log("SUCCESS")
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                if (error.response) {
                    dispatch(resetLoading())
                    dispatch(getNewsFailure(error.response))
                } else if (error.request) {
                    dispatch(resetLoading())
                    dispatch(getNewsFailure(error.request))
                } else {
                    dispatch(resetLoading())
                    dispatch(getNewsFailure(error.message))
                }
                dispatch(resetLoading(error.config))
                dispatch(getNewsFailure(error.config))
            });
    }
}
```

**/reducers/news.js**

```
import { GET_NEWS_SUCCESS, GET_NEWS_FAILURE, LOADING, PULL_LOADING, RESET_LOADING, RESET_PULL_LOADING } from '../../action/deliverer/news'

export const _INITIAL_STATE_ = {
    loading: false,
    pull_loading: false,
}

export default function (state = _INITIAL_STATE_, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case RESET_LOADING: {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
            }
        }
        case RESET_PULL_LOADING: {
            return {
                ...state,
                pull_loading: false,
            }
        }
        case LOADING:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true,
                error: null
            }
        case PULL_LOADING:
            return {
                ...state,
                update_loading: true,
            }
        case GET_NEWS_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                list: action.news
            }
        case GET_NEWS_FAILURE:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                error: action.error,
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

**/reducers.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'

import kitorder from './student/kitorder'
import kittracking from './student/kittracking'
import article from './student/article'
import login from './deliverer/login'
import notif from './deliverer/notif'
import news from './deliverer/news'
import profil from './deliverer/profil'

const rootPersistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage: AsyncStorage,
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({ kitorder, kittracking, article, login, notif, news, profil })

export const persistedReducer = persistReducer(rootPersistConfig, rootReducer)
```

To illustrate the problem here is the behavior in action

[image: To illustrate the problem here is the behavior in action]

Comment: Can you show the selectors and component where the data is displayed?

Comment: Have you verified yet that the data is actually unset in redux? You can console log the action type and the new state in the profile reducer. Also is deliverer/profil the same as reducer/profil.js? What's going on there?

Comment: Hi @windowsill, ur right, i console log my action type in reducer and in the file /actions/profil.js there were an error in constants declaration, thank you for your help, fatigue is playing tricks on me.